# How can I delete files (in a transaction-like manner) from MongoDB's GridFS using the Mongo console

Tags: mongodb, filesystems, gridfs, nosql

I need to delete a bunch of files, stored in Mongo's GridFS that are older than a given date. This implies that I'd need to delete from both **fs.files** and **fs.chunks** collections.

I was thinking of writing a function that finds all documents from **fs.files** that match the search criteria, iterate over them and in the loop delete all documents from **fs.chunks** that match the *files_id* value of the corresponding document in **fs.files**, however, according to the docs:

> *MongoDB supports atomic operations on single documents.  MongoDB does not support traditional locking and complex transactions*

which makes me think my suggested approach might not be the correct one.

I know I could use one of the client drivers to manipulate the GridFS directly. For example, using PHP I could implement it like this:

```
<?php
$grid = $db->getGridFS('fs');

$grid->remove(array(
    "uploadDate" => array(
        '$lt' => new MongoDate(strtotime("2011-02-01 00:00:00"))
    )
));
```

... however I wish to accomplish this using only the mongo console.

So, what is the preferred way to remove files, matching certain criteria regarding a field in **fs.files** from both collections, using the mongo console, or a JS file, feeding the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggested approach is mostly correct.  The only pointer to a file's contents is in fs.files, so if you delete that first and something goes wrong deleting the chunks, at least nothing will be hanging around that could reference those chunks.

To be on the safe side, you could have a background job that goes through the files_id field of the chunks collection (which is indexed, so it should be fast) and makes sure all files_ids match up with docs in the fs.files collection.  If they don't and they weren't created relatively recently (you can get the timestamp they were created at from the _id field), you can delete them.  (You wouldn't want to delete recently created chunks, in case they are part of a file currently being inserted.)

Comment: Kristina, thanks for your feedback! Generally what would you recommend - go with the console way, or use the PHP driver like in the example above? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do whichever you'd like.  They're normal collections, so you can access them with db.fs.files and db.fs.chunks from the console.

Comment: Thanks, Kristina!

Here's how I implemented it, in case someone else is interested: http://pastebin.com/9Zcxtmt4